# Programming multi-GPU applications with one kernel spanning several cards/

Tags: cuda, gpu

I am interested in using CUDA to program a multi-GPU application.

As far as I know, one can use multiple GPU's to execute 2 or more kernels execute simultaneously in parallel. Each kernel's data resides on the GPU it is executing on.

But what if I want my data and kernel operation to span several cards. How does one do this?

The `simpleMultiGPU` example in the CUDA SDK is not what I want since it basically launches the same kernel on multiple GPUs. No inter GPU communication is present, which is what I am interested in.

Comment: You dont even have intra gpu communication between blocks working on the same kernel. I am not sure I get the question. May be you can clarify on what you want.

Comment: @Pavan, blocks on the same kernel can communicate (via atomic memory operations, for example).  They just can't synchronize.

Comment: @harrism, my bad. I honestly never used communication between parallel processes for anything other than synchronization.

Comment: The only reason for synchronization is communication, no? (sharing is communication, IMO).  Perhaps you can think of a non-communication usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're interested in Unified Virtual Addressing (UVA) and P2P communication. Consult http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/cuda_webinars_GPUDirect_uva.pdf . You should not be communicating between different CUDA blocks anyway, but the techniques I mention should at least allow you to read data and write data across multiple GPUs, access the data in more flexible ways.

Comment: As I commented above: communication between blocks is OK using atomics.  Intra-block _synchronization_ is what you want to avoid.

Comment: @harrism A fair criticism: communication is fine as long as there's no synchronization. Generally speaking, I'd be curious how often this kind of communication occurs... perhaps an example?

Comment: Atomics were slow in their first implementations, but are getting much faster and therefore much more useful.  So, for example, one might maintain a global counter that all blocks can increment.  A more complex/realistic example is performing per-block scans to determine pool allocation sizes needed for each whole block, and an atomic add to get the pointer offset for each block (since allocation location order doesn't matter, a globally-ordered scan is not required so the atomic is more efficient).  Those are just off the top of my head.